# PHP terminates script unexpectedly

Tags: php

I'm working in PHP and creating a system with a lot of PHP-driven elements and I have noticed that some of my pages stop displaying text produced using the `echo` command.

I have made a small example of this. Of course, my program is not supposed to just print allt numbers from 1 to 10000, but this example demonstrates how the script just terminates without any warnings.

Example code:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
        echo $i, '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Output:

> 1
>   2
>   More numbers...
>   8975
>   8976
>   8977
>   8

What is causing this? Is it a buffer issue, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Does it always end on exactly the same number? How long does it take?

Comment: This smells like a timeout - nothing inherently wrong with the code. Could you provide some more information on what else you are doing?

Comment: Run "time php -f your_script.php" and check the output. If the time it took to execute is some round number like 30 seconds it's very likely it's timeout.

Comment: You haven't given any indication of the timeout.  Does setting the time limit set_time_limit (seconds) make any difference?

Comment: Running from a terminal actually prints all numbers, but the time command doesn't work. I am on a Windows machine.

Comment: I concur, it smells like a timeout. If you haven't enabled error reporting in your dev environment you should, I have a feeling you'll get the answer you're looking for right away. The quick and dirty way to enable error reporting is to add the following line(s) right under your script's opening `<?php ` tag: `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: Setting a different time limit does not matter, and it always stopps on the same number after each compilation. If I add or remove a few "dummy" lines around the for-statement (even after it!) the number changes to remain the same until the file is saved again.

Comment: Error reporting is no good, and I get no errors.

Comment: @Paul that's actually perfectly valid. Have a look at the argument signature for [`echo()`](http://docs.php.net/echo), it actually accepts a variadic number of expressions as parameters; e.g: `echo 'foo', 'bar', 'baz';`

Comment: When I run it through xdebug, it tells me that the script is still running after it has printed the last number that it prints. It then asks me if I want to stop the execution, but it has clearly stopped running.

Comment: What's your memory limit, out of curiousity? `echo ini_get('memory_limit');`. That said, you'd expect to see a fatal error if you transgressed this limit.

Comment: @Darragh my memory limit is set to 128 MB and it's the same in both the terminal and on the running web server on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your code ran to completion on the cli suggests to me that your script is exceeding the [`ini.max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) runtime configuration.

Note in the linked documentation that the value of this configuration on the cli is `0` which means it does not time out when run in that environment.

The default setting in the browser is `30` seconds.

You can show your current setting in the browser with:

```
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

And you should be able to increase it with:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // turns off timeout
```

Comment: The execution time is noway near 30 seconds, it's around one to three seconds at most, but I will try it.

Comment: Interesting... that's really short. if it's that low then it could be another problem; something memory based. In any case, it would be a good idea to ascertain what the `max_execution_time` is.

Comment: The `max_execution_time` was 30, but I set it to run forever now.

Comment: Did it work? If that works and you have follow on `memory_limit` problems, you should see a fatal error at least if you have the appropriate `error_reporting` settings enabled.

Comment: Sadly, it did not work @Darragh and I have `error_reporting` set such that all errors should be shown. Not even the log file contains anything.

Comment: Really bizarre! Sorry that can't help. I'm out of ideas for the moment I'm afraid :( I assume you've looked at the error and access logs, and that there is nothing in there either.

Answer (score 0):

If the script you have shown us behaves as you describe the there's something very wrong going on. If this is a Unix or Linux based system and its repeatedly exhibiting this behaviour then the kernel is terminating the script - unless it has been configured not to do so, the kernel will be forcing a core dump of the process.

Either go build a new system to run your code on or Google how to capture and diagnose a core dump on your operating system.

**update**

If xdebug is reporting the process is still running then it probably hasn't dumped its core, but "not producing output" != "not running". What state is the process in? What happens when you redirect the ouput? What is the end-to-end output channel when it misbehaves?

Comment: The Appace PHP interpreter seems to freeze completely, perhaps there is a deadlock somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem did not lie directly with my PHP installation or the application itself, but somewhere in my IDE PHPStorm. When running the code with the same PHP interpreter outside of the IDE's wrappers, it all works fine. The procedures described by the many users here helped with that. Thank you.